# .NET Core - Get parent assembly name in integration tests

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-assembly

I have integration test project which is hosted in memory using`Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` package. Then I have library that is used in these tests. I want to get assembly name of **tests project** **from** **my library**. So structure looks like this.

```
TestHost --> TestProject --> MyLibrary
```

What I've done is to try call following methods:

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` returns MyLibrary assembly

`Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` returns MyLibrary assembly

`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` returns TestHost assembly.

There is any way to get this without specify this explicitly by passing assembly from TestProject to MyLibrary ?

**EDIT**

As @svoychik suggested I've also tried calling `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` directly from method where `TestProject` calls `MyLibrary` but this returns this:

> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

Comment: Have you looked at this? : https://www.codeproject.com/tips/791878/get-calling-assembly-from-stacktrace

Comment: I don't have a good answer to your question but may I ask *why* you want this information?

Comment: If you not loadding `MyLibrary` dynamically, you can calculate parent assembly with `GetReferencedAssemblies`.

Comment: @Stefan yes, this returns also `System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_Assembly_GetCallingAssembly) GetCallingAssembly:

> Returns the Assembly of the method that invoked the currently
>   executing method

Therefore you can retrieve the calling assembly TestProject only in the method which is called **directly** by TestProject. If calling assembly is needed in another part of the code, it can be saved in a variable to use the value later

---

Example:
Assuming you have TestProject -> TestLibrary

*TestProject*

```
public class TestClass
    {
        public void TestWrite()
        {
            new ConsoleWriter().Write("hello world");
        }
    }
```

*TestLibrary*

```
namespace TestLibrary
{
    public class ConsoleWriter
    {
        public void Write(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName());
            Test();
        }

        private void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In test method");
            Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName());
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
hello world
TestProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
In test method
TestLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've also tried this, and what I get is this `System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral`

Answer (score 0):

With certain assumptions you can potentially use Stacktrace class for something like this. This will not easily work in all the cases.

To make it work and without making it more complex we'd need to assume the code is not called from a different thread, other then the thread running the testhost. And use a naming convention with our dlls. Then we can check the current stack trace during the test run and attempt to establish "our" dlls in the call hierarchy.

You can use code similar to this one:

```
            var method = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace()
               .GetFrames()
               .Select(x => x.GetMethod())
               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.DeclaringType.FullName.Contains("Contoso");
```

Where Contoso is part of the name of each dll within our system (our naming convention). Alternatively you can also filter out anything, which you don't want:

```
           var method = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace()
               .GetFrames()
               .Select(x => x.GetMethod())
               .Where(x => !x.DeclaringType.FullName.Contains("XUnit") && !x.DeclaringType.FullName.Contain("System")).ToList();
```

In each case you can retrieve further information from the method, such as module, assembly names, paths etc.. It can be useful, when the test bootstrapping logic is complex and requires extended logging.